# Blender 2.79 crashing

Tags: windows

Blender has recently started crashing if I open any other software (I like to have the Blender online manual open and a text file to refer to preferred workflows) and try to return to Blender. Or it just crashes. I have plenty of RAM and try not to do stupid re keeping too many programs open. Other resource-intensive software, such as Marvelous Designer and PhotoShop are working fine.

Things I've tried:
Win10 updates
Re-downloading and re-installing Blender
Re-downloading and re-installing my NVidia graphics card driver
Disabling (or trying to disable) Win10 updates to the NVidia graphics card driver
Uninstalling the Intel HD Graphics card driver - I'm only plugged into the NVidia card

Suggestions? This is making me nuts and costing me work.

Comment: Sorry - details: CPU i7-4790 @3.60GHz, RAM16.0 GB, NVidia Quadro M2000, Windows 10 Pro v1803x

Comment: Have you tried opening a cmd window and running blender from the command line?  You might get error messages that would help you track down the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I tried it and Blender seemed to open normally without error. (I am no programmer, so I very well could be missing something)

Comment: I 'think' I've maybe narrowed it down to a driver problem, or maybe corrupted OS file, and I'm working on that, so far with no success at all. And I don't know why Blender is affected but none of my other 3d CGI software. Blender still silently fails if I open a text file or browser, then either return to Blender or close that software. I've been able to rule out RAM issues.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful for anyone having Blender crashy issues - it turned out that, even though Blender was the only software having a problem, and after trying everything else, I had to rebuild my (Win10Pro) OS from the ground up. Fortunately I keep most software and all data on portable drives so this wasn't as bad as it sounds. Anyway, Blender is now working predictably.